# Which incarnation of The Doctor does Adrian resemble?

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who series 8 episode 6 *The Caretaker*, Clara has a friend named Adrian. When the Doctor looks at him, he looks like he recognizes him. Later, there are these conversations

> DOCTOR: Go and canoodle with your boyfriend. Come on. I wasn't born yesterday. Far from it.
>
> CLARA: You did recognise him.
>
> DOCTOR: Possibly reminded me of a certain dashing young time traveller.
>
> CLARA: Oh, of course you recognised him. I. Sorry. Stupid. I, I underestimated you.

...

> DOCTOR: What about the handsome one, the one with the bow tie?
>
> CLARA: Who? Adrian? No, no, no. He's just a friend and not my type.

...

> DANNY: So, there's an alien, that used to look like Adrian. Then he turned into a Scottish caretaker.

Does Adrian look like a past incarnation of the Doctor?

Which doctor does Adrian resemble ?

Comment: but when the doctor said Possibly reminded me of a certain dashing young time traveller. why dint clara realized he was talking about 11th matt smith

Comment: Because they had just met Orson Pink, Danny's descendant in *Listen*. Clara thought he was talking about him. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: what would she have said if she did realize it was the 11th Matt smith

Answer (score 10):

I think it's self explanatory. Adrian looks like the Doctor's previous incarnation, the one played by Matt Smith. He even wears a bow tie, and probably thinks they're cool!!

The Doctor felt flattered when he thought Clara was dating someone who looked like his past self.

Eleventh Doctor (picture taken from Wikipedia)

[image: This is the Eleventh Doctor]

Adrian Davis (Picture taken from tardis.wikia.com)

[image: This is Adrian Davis, according to Tardis.wikia.com]

The reason Clara didn't make the connection, was because they had just met Orson Pink, Danny's descendant, in the episode *Listen*. She thought he meant him, not his past self.